# Maps on compactifications

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be locally compact hausdorff spaces. Then one can look at their one point compactification. Now let $\iota_X : X\to X\coprod Y$ be the canonical inclusion map. Does this map extend to a map $\iota_X^+: X^+\to (X\coprod Y)^+$ by sending the points at infinity to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implicitly assuming that that $X$ is not compact.

$\iota _X:X\to X \coprod Y$ by $\iota_X(x)=x$.

$X^+=X\cup\{\infty\}$ and the neighborhoods of $\infty$ are of the form $\{\infty\}\cup U$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $X\setminus U$ is compact.

Let $\infty'$ be the point added to $X \coprod Y$.

Now define $\iota ^+ _X$ by $\iota^+ _X(x)=x$ and $\iota^+ _X (\infty)=\infty '$.

Clearly $\iota ^+ _X$ is an extension of $\iota _X$ mapping the points at infinity to each other.

We can show that $\iota ^+ _X$ is continuous. Let $U$ be open in $X \coprod Y$.

Case 1: $\infty'\notin U$. Then  $\iota ^{+{-1}}  _X [U]=U\cap X$ is open in $X$.

Case 2: $\infty'\in U$. Then $\big(X \coprod Y\big) \setminus U$ is compact. Since $X$ is closed in $X \coprod Y$, we have that $X\setminus U$ is compact. Thus $\iota ^{+{-1}}  _X [U]=\{\infty\}\cup (U\cap X)$ is an open neighborhood of $\infty$ in $X$.